# Multiple JSON parses + parsing top 10 games from Twitch API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright. So the following code fetches only the first channel from the list, I want it to be fetching all the streams from the JSON. ( Bonus question: How can I format all the fetched streams into a nice row-per-row grid which features three streams in each row )

```
<script>
     var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams";
     $.getJSON(twitchApi, function (json) {
     var streamGame = json.streams[0].game;
     var streamThumb = json.streams[0].preview;
     var streamVideo = json.streams[0].name;
     $('#twitch').append('<li><iframe src="http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=' + streamVideo + '"></iframe></li>');
    }
   );
</script>
```

And the second thing I need help with is how to create a script which fetches the top 10 games from this JSON : https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/games/top .. Should be quite similar to the one above but my brain is frozen and I need to finish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fetching more than one stream at same time with the same data you can use a **for** loop.

Fixed your streamVideo variable, ".channel" was missing before ".name"(I recommed using a JSON viewer to get a clear vision of the structure, like [Online JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

And made the script so 10 iframes are displayed(also grabbed the embed code from twitch, your embed was so small).

The styling I let it to your own, I know nothing about styling iframes, you can try setting 30% width for each, so there are 3 per row, and the others go in the bottom row.

```js
  var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams";
  $.getJSON(twitchApi, function(json) {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var streamGame = json.streams[i].game;
      var streamThumb = json.streams[i].preview;
      var streamVideo = json.streams[i].channel.name;
      $('#twitch').append('<li><iframe src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=' + streamVideo + '" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="378" width="620"></iframe><li>');
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I've done 10 minutes ago. Great response. I'll pick this as a top answer for anyone who's stuck with the same problem.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do this?
And the second thing I need help with is how to create a script which fetches the top 10 games from this JSON : https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/games/top .. Should be quite similar to the one above but my brain is frozen and I need to finish this.

Comment: Prerry much the same:
  `var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/games/top"
  $.getJSON(twitchApi, function (json) {
   for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    var topGame = json.top[i].game.name;
    $('#twitch').append('<li>' + topGame + '</li>');
   }
  });`

Comment: Sorry was editing the answer so the code looks better, try this: 
 `var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/games/top";
  $.getJSON(twitchApi, function(json) {
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var topGame = json.top[i].game.name;
    $('#twitch').append('<li>' + topGame + '</li>');
   }
  }); `

Comment: Do you know by any chance how I can make more videos load on click? I've got 9 atm and I've placed a button underneath them, I'd like 9 more to load when pressed, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can get what you need to get done with a combination of loops and inline-block elements. Here, I used jQuery to create rows of three cells each.

```
var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams";                                                                                                                          
$.getJSON(twitchApi, function (json) {
    var streamRow = $("<div class='stream-row'></div>").appendTo("#twitch"); // Create first row.
    var streamCell;
    var streamVideo;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.streams.length; i++)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0 && i > 0)
        {
            // Create a new row every multiple of 3.
            streamRow = $("<div class='stream-row'></div>");
            $("#twitch").append(streamRow);
        }
        // Create a cell with a video and add it to the row.
        streamVideo = json.streams[i].channel.name;
        streamCell = $("<div>", {
            css: {
                "class": "stream-cell",
                "display": "inline-block"
            }
        });
        streamCell.append('<iframe src="http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=' + streamVideo + '"></iframe>');
        streamRow.append(streamCell);
    }
});
```

You use another loop for the top ten thing. The API already returns 10 games, so I used the length instead of hard-coding 10.

```
var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/games/top";                                                                                                                        
$.getJSON(twitchApi, function (json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.top.length; i++)
    {
        // Do whatever you need here with the info from the JSON.
        console.log(json.top[i].game.name)
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, it appears that it stacks on it's own. I shrinked the div size and they all fitted the way they should. To separate them I've used a transparent border and it looks great.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Do you have any clue about this?
And the second thing I need help with is how to create a script which fetches the top 10 games from this JSON : api.twitch.tv/kraken/games/top .. Should be quite similar to the one above but my brain is frozen and I need to finish this.

Comment: It's the exact same construct as the first part. Updated my answer.

Comment: Do you know by any chance how I can make more videos load on click? I've got 9 atm and I've placed a button underneath them, I'd like 9 more to load when pressed, and so on.